# Is it possible to have Stream as a parameter to a WCF Data Service Operation?

Tags: wcf, file-upload, wcf-data-services

Please note this question is specific to WCF Data Services not normal Wcf Service.

I'm trying to upload a file to the service without any luck.

As soon as I add the following code:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
public void UploadPic(Guid id, Stream fileContents)
{
    myImageSaver.SaveImageFromStream(fileContents);
}
```

My whole data service crashes. I cannot query any of the entity sets. I just get the Blue WCF Screen of death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass a stream as a prameter to a service operation, only primitive types are supported as parameters to service operations. The proper way of supporting streams in WCF Data Services is to use either the MLE/MR functionality. Take a look at this blog series for a detailed walkthrough of how to implement such service:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/08/04/data-services-streaming-provider-series-implementing-a-streaming-provider-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, see the example here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1376821.aspx/1

Comment: Your answer is un-helpful. Please take note of my first comment. I'm not asking about rest services, I'm asking about .net 4.0 WCF Data Services.

Comment: Yes, but you are using the WebInvoke attribute which is part of the WebHttpBinding which is REST.

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing it wrong :). it's not working. I was hoping someone could post a sample of how to do image upload with a wcf data service.